# controll the size of image assigned to the background by ui colorpattern

Tags: swift, imageview, drawing

I assign an image to the background so the user can draw on it but the image always is not in the right size it takes like 1/3 of it and assigns it to the image view 
the only way to bypass this is to make a canvas exactly the size of the image assigned like in PICSART app,
does any one knows how to do this?

```
mainimageview.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: "draw")
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own method to resize the image you want at the time of assigning background color. Pass your image and size you want

```
func imageWithImage(image:UIImage?, newSize:CGFloat)->UIImage?
{
    let size = CGSizeMake(newSize, newSize)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```